# Where or what is the guitar table

Tags: classical-guitar, classical-music

I have just done a classical guitar test and one of my comments was not to put my right hand on the guitar table. Can anyone tell me what it is, i am just using a standard classical guitar and no google results say what it is. I am guessing it is just near the bridge but if i am wrong plear correct me.

Comment: In what nation and in what language was this "guitar test"? I'm curious as to who would use the term "table" in this context.

Comment: I see he or she responded to the question's answer in Spanish. Table translates to Mesa... in reverse, Mesa can be Table but can also be Board... perhaps "board" (in Spanish) short for "soundboard" (whatever that is in Spanish) led to the confusion?

Comment: Its Australian.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **top** of an acoustic guitar (steel-string or classical) is also referred to as the **table**. This is the flat piece of wood making up the front of the guitar's body when in playing position (which is a bit confusing!) It is the flat piece of wood which has the sound-hole in it, and which has the bridge stuck to it. This part of the guitar is also called the **sound-board** or **face**.

Here is my own quick sketch showing which bit of the guitar is the table (try not to laugh too much...):

[image]

When playing with a standard classical guitar technique, it is best not to rest the right-hand or any of the right-hand fingers on the table, as it restricts the hand's movement, making it difficult to play all of the strings easily with the thumb and fingers.

Comment: gracias mucho , su información es muy apreciado

Comment: Wow, I've never heard this before. I wonder if it's primarily used in classical guitar circles.

Comment: I've certainly heard other classical guitarists use this term, if not often. I've also read the term in books about classical guitar. But I hadn't heard it used for steel-string acoustic until I checked some online sources today.

Comment: Though some 19th century method books do allow, or even encourage resting the little finger on the sound board.  Ukuleles are still played that way.

Comment: That's true; I've certainly seen that in the diagrams in Sor's teaching materials, and others too. But I haven't seen any modern classical guitarists using this as an orthodox technique.

Answer (score -1):

"Don't put your arms on the guitar table" is a tongue-in-cheek way of telling you to fix your posture, it references the age-old lament of parents everywhere trying to instill dinner-table etiquette into their teenagers:  "get yer darned elbows OFF THE TABLE..."   :)

Comment: This is an interesting explanation, but I doubt it's true. Have you got any reference for this claim, please?